# Enterprise Security Application Block in Conjunction With MembershipProvider in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, architecture, enterprise-library, application-blocks

Looking to implement authentication/authorisation for ASP.NET app

Was looking into using Provider model MembershipProvider SQLServerMembershipProvider etc as makes good sense to me.

However I'm looking into the Enterprise Security Application block as well. My question is can/should the two be used in tandem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these two components would play together nicely. In fact, one is built upon the other.

The more important question is, do you need *both* for your particular scenario? Look at [what the MembershipProvider functionality gives you out of the box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx). What is it that the EntLib Security Block adds to this that is necessary for your application?